# Fonts too thin when A4 scaled down to A5 in printing

Tags: fonts, best-practices, printing, font-encodings

In my document I am using the same settings as in the MWE below. I need copies of the document in A4 and A5. Both have to be identical so I cannot optimise the appearance of both by using `a4paper` for the A4 copies and `a5paper` for the A5 copies. The A5 copies are hence produced simply by scaling them down on the printer.

The *problem*:

The fonts in the A5 copies are so thin that in some cases the lower part of the little e, for example, is not even visible --> see the image at the bottom of the question (it's a scan of the print-out; the problem is visible, for instance, in the word "discrete"; of course, the low quality of the image is partially due to the scan quality but the problem with the e's is not due to the scan itself). NB: The copy shop is a professional one with over 25 years of experience so I don't think the problem is due to unprofessional handling of printers.

My *question*:

- I use PDFLaTeX. Should I rather use LaTeX + dvi2ps + ps2pdf? The lady in the copy shop says that using Ghostscript for ps -> pdf might produce better pdf's.
- Should I use different font settings?
- Is there any method to scale the A4 output down to A5 already in LaTeX? Would this improve the font quality in the A5 copies?

Unfortunately, I do not have a laser printer anywhere near where I am right now. So I can't try and look whether the printing output improves when I change settings.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  textwidth=16cm,
  outer=2cm,
  textheight=45\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  includehead=true,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={PDFLaTeX}
            ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

PS: I have prepared the document for A4. Due to time constraints changing everything to A5 + 10 pt and scaling up in the printer for A4 is not really an option, since this would mean I would have to go over all formulae in displays and make adjustments so that they fit into the new textwidth. (It's quite a long document.)

Comment: use another font, eg `\usepackage{tgpagella}`

Comment: Is this a common font? Never heard of it. Should I use it in addition to the settings I have now or does it replace something? Sorry, though having some elementary understanding of LaTeX I don't know anything about fonts! :-(

Comment: put it right after the `fontenc`. And yes, it is a common font, the free Palatino from the TeX Gyre Project

Comment: Does it replace `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`?

Comment: In general, if you're going to *print* on A5, then you'd be much better off if you were to *design* for A5 (I.e `a5paper`, smaller font sizes, possibly even ragged right). Simply scaling stuff generally doesn't give good results.

Comment: @B.L. Sure, but the problem is that I need print-outs in both A4 and A5 and they must be identical. I don't think that in this case one can find an optimal solution for both. Hence, I would like to optimise the A5 output under the constraint that the A4 output shouldn't get worse.

Comment: @lpdbw: no, `inputenc` is different to `fontenc`, both are needed for `pdflatex`. As I wrote: put `\usepackage{tgpagella}` behind the `fontenc` sequence

Comment: You can design for a5 an then scale up to a4

Comment: A problem I notice now is that with `tgpagella` there is a strange discrepancy between the appearance of the main text and formulae: math stuff is still in the thin font!

Comment: @lpdbw With math, use ``\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`` instead of ``tgpagella``.

Comment: @lpdbw: Or use `\usepackage{pxfonts}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different font, e.g.

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
```

or

```
\usepackage{pxfonts}
```

However, much better would be to use `a5paper` paper format if you're going to print your document on A5 paper. To change various dimensions on the paper (margins etc.), use e.g. the package `geometry`.